# Combination problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

How many way can UNC, Duke, and Florida State finish 1-2-3 in the AAC regular season rankings?

Would I have to find out the AAC'S regular season rankings?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the number of [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of three objects.  You have three choices for the first, two for the second, and one for the third, which are multiplied to give $3!=6$